# How can I append an integer to the link name?

Tags: javascript, html

i have defined the following JavaScript:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html = ' ';
var i = 1 ;

if ( "#variable.1#" != null) {
    html += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=#variable.1#" >"View Page" + i </a></div>';
i =i +1;
}

if ( "#variable.2#" != null) {
   html  += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=#variable.2#"> "View Page"  i </a></div>';
i = i=1;
}

if ( "#variable.3#" !=null) {
    html += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=#variable.3#" >"View Page" + i </a></div>';
i = i+1;
}


document.write(html);
</script>
```

but the output of the above javascript incase all the variables are not null will be:-

```
"View Page" + i
"View Page" i
"View Page" + i
```

so how i can force the output to be 
External Intigration Images

```
View Page 1
View Page 2
View Page 3
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to read some tutorials instead of posting a question every time a trivial problem comes up.

Comment: `"#variable.3#" != null` will be always true

Comment: why will the above be always true ???

Comment: because it is a string and it is not null =)

Comment: @johnG Something is `null` only if you set it as `null`. If you are referring to `undefined`, well then that's more of a possibility but will never be the case because a filled-in string is defined (which is not null...and obviously not undefined)

Comment: so how i can chekc if the value in null or not ??

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
html += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=#variable.3#" >View Page '+i+'</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your strings as follows:

```
html += '<div><a href="/Service1.svc/vf/img?imgid=#variable.3#" >"View Page" ' + i + '</a></div>'
```

This will take the value of `i` and append it into the string, not `i` itself.

As an additional bit of information, keep in mind that in JavaScript when a string is added to an integer, the integer is parsed as a string rather than the inverse. As is noted in the comment,

```
var answer = 1 + 1 + "1"
// answer = 21, not "111" and not 3
```

Comment: String parsing does not "execute before integer parsing", whatever that means. The correct operator is used based on what types are being operated on. As soon as a string is encountered in the expression, string concatenation is used from then on. Otherwise, the correct operation is used. For example, `1 + 1 + "1"` does not equal `111` like you think...it equals `"21"`

Comment: *Nowhere did I suggest that 1 + 1 + "1" would equal 3. That was not my example and I did not "think" that.* The point I was trying to make was precisely what you said in as much as given a string and an int, the + (string concatenation) will take precedence over the + (integer addition) if you attempt to add a string to an int. I would be happy to amend my answer with better wording if you could suggest something which better communicates this concept.

Comment: I know what you meant, but you used an example with 2 variables, which doesn't demonstrate the way it works. You could include what you said about left-to-right precedence and the fact that normal operations occur until a string is encountered, and causes concatenation to happen the rest of the operation